# Ignite Cache Sum of values

Tags: java, ignite

I am using Ignite tutorial code (link below), but I want to modify it such that it operates on a different type of data and the counts are done differently - rather than incrementing counter by 1 I want to add a current value.

So let's assume I have number of occurences of a certain word in different documents, so let's assume I have something like this:

*'the' 6586*

*'the' 925*

So I want Cache to hold 
'the' 7511

So given this:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            lines.forEach(line -> {
              Stream<String> words = Stream.of(line.split(" "));
              List<String> tokens = words.collect(Collectors.toList());
              // this is just to emphasize that I want to pass value
              Long value = Long.parseLong(tokens.get(1));
              stmr.addData(tokens.get(0), Long.parseLong(tokens.get(1));
```

I would like the *value* to be passed to the stmr.receiver() method, so I can add it to the *val*.

I have even tried creating a class variable in StreamWords that would store the value, but the value does not get updated, and in stmr.receiver() it is still 0 ( as initialized).

Link to tutorial:
[Word Count Ignite Example](http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/v1.1/docs/streaming-example/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. In stmr.receiver(), arg is actually the value that I would like to insert, so just cast it to the object of your desire and you should be able to get the value.